# After using catkin_make the executable exists 2 times

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After making with catkin_make, when I start my node with rosrun, I get the following message:

You have chosen a non-unique executable, please pick one of the following:

1. /home/name/ros/devel/lib/gero_move/servo_driver
2. /home/name/ros/src/gero_move/servo_driver

CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(gero_move)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs gero_msgs message_generation)
catkin_package( CATKIN_DEPENDS gero_msgs)
add_executable(servo_driver servo_driver.cpp)
```

I use Ubuntu and ROS Indigo. Even if I delete build and devel directory and make catkin_make again, it creates both files new. What could be root cause for this?

Thanks for any help :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191655/after-using-catkin_make-the-executable-exists-2-times/) by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-01**:
Can you edit your question to add your CMakeLists.txt?

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-09-01**:
Thanks for your kind request, I added it.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-01**:
not sure, but please try to rename your .cpp file with another name and try again: for istance:
add_executable(servo_driver main_servo.cpp)

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-09-02**:
Thanks a lot for your help, when I delete it in the src directory, it does not get recreated again by catkin_make. So I assume it is right, that the executable is only in the devel directory?What do I do with data files I have to read in, do I have to make catkin copy this file to the devel directo?

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-09-02**:
Ok, I found out that working directory is the workspace, for me home/jonny/ros. So if I place data files there, I can access them with a relative pathname. Thanks a lot for all your answeres, it helped me a lot!! :-) Ahendirx, can you convert your comment to an answer, so I can mark as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your CMakeLists.txt looks reasonable. Have you tried removing the executable in the src directory and confirming that it gets recreated when you do a build?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-09-02**:
after removing in the src directory "src/gero_move/servo_driver" the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometime you will find more executables in the same package. Of course they are compiled with different `name_file.cpp` files.
Look into you `CMakeLists.txt` and be sure you don t have 2 times the same add_executable.
For istance:

```
add_executable( my_robot src/main_a.cpp )
add_executable( my_robot src/main_b.cpp )   <= this is redundant with the line above
```

Hope it helps

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-09-01**:
Thanks for your kind reply. Unfortunately I only use the "add_executable" once... I added cmakelists.txt above.